# Function to execute a string as PHP code and return the printed text from code

Tags: php, function, output, eval

I am trying to create a function that would parse php code and return the result in pure text, as if it was being read in a browser. Like this one:

```
public function PHPToText($data, $php_text) {
    //TODO code
    return $text; 
}
```

I would call the function like this, with the params that you see below:

```
$data = array('email' => 'test@so.com');
$string = "<?= " . '$data' . "['email']" . "?>";

$text = $this->PHPToText($data, $string);
```

Now `echo $text` should give: *test@so.com*

Any ideas or a function that can achieve this nicely?

Comment: i am having trouble understanding what the function should do..

Comment: I've voted up all answers for remembering the bads of eval(), though don't be afraid to use it. Just take care what you are evaling. Of course dont eval directly user input, but use it nevertheless. All php functions have a reason to be there.

Comment: php code is never read by the browser, the server does everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bad bad bad bad bad idea, but basically:

```
function PHPToText($data, $string) {
    ob_start();
    eval($string);
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

You really should reconsider this sort of design. Executing dynamically generated code is essentially NEVER a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

in this case it should be done with eval()

But always remember: eval is evil!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the `eval()` function http://www.php.net/eval in order to parse the tags inside your variable `$string`